# Set individual file priority (single torrent): Transmission

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

Is there a way to set priorities per file in a given torrent? The files tab only lets me change the names of files and has no other option. If not, is there other software that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deluge has that option to give priorities(like high,low,normal) to individual files inside the download file.
You can install deluge from software centre or from terminal with this command

> > sudo apt-get install deluge

Comment: but to answer the original question, can transmission then not do this?

Comment: transmission has very few options when i used it in ubuntu 12.04 it has no option to set individual file priority

Answer (score 22):

In Properties on the Files tab, expand the window so that the priority column is visible.  You may have to make the name column narrower.

Then click on the text of the priority, where it says 'Normal'.  Each click cycles through Low, Normal, High.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Priorities are available, but you have to shift the columns to make them visible.

Answer (score 1):

QBittorrent also has the options to set priority for downloaded files.

```
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

See screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Transmission 2.82 also allows priority to be changed in the torrent's Properties->Options tab, at the bottom of the Speed section.

Answer (score -1):

You might be facing the same thing that I noticed...
In [Torrent] Properties -> Files (tab), try to resize the "Names" column making it smaller then the rest of the options (have, download, options) should appear.
This is probably a bug in the GTK interface about the horizontal scrolling.